# Why does HorizontalPager's automatic scrolling stop after manual scrolling?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, jetpack-compose-accompanist

I have a `HorizontalPager`

```
val pageCount = bannerList.size
val startIndex = Int.MAX_VALUE / 2
val pagerState = rememberPagerState(initialPage = 100)
HorizontalPager(
    count = Int.MAX_VALUE,
    state = pagerState,
    contentPadding = PaddingValues(
        horizontal = 20.dp
    ),
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
) { index ->
// content goes here
}
```

and I made it scrolling every 4 second like banners with `LaunchedEffect`

```
LaunchedEffect(
    key1 = Unit,
    block = {
        repeat(
            times = Int.MAX_VALUE,
            action = {
                delay(
                    timeMillis = 4000
                )
                pagerState.animateScrollToPage(
                    page = pagerState.currentPage + 1
                )
            }
        )
    })
```

it scrolls fine every 4 second but when i scroll it manually `HorizontalPager` stops scrolling!

any suggestions how to fix this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`animateScrollToPage` throws an exception when called during manual scrolling:

```kotlin
java.util.concurrent.CancellationException: Current mutation had a higher priority
```

You can solve it in many ways. For example just catch the exception and ignore it:

```kotlin
delay(
    timeMillis = 4000
)
try {
    pagerState.animateScrollToPage(
        page = pagerState.currentPage + 1
    )
} catch (_: Throwable) {
}
```

An other option is to check whether the pager is being dragged and stop your `LaunchedEffect` for this period of time:

```kotlin
val isDragged by pagerState.interactionSource.collectIsDraggedAsState()
if (!isDragged) {
    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

I think the second solution is cleaner, because in this case the timer will be restarted, and delay until the next scroll will always be the same.

Comment: 2nd action awesomely working. Thank you for saving my time!!